# How to prevent user to access login page in django when already logged in?

Tags: python, django, django-login

In my django application, user can access login/signup pages through URL even after logged-in. How to prevent them from accessing these pages?

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
  path('signup/', views.register, name='register'),
  path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Though I can write *if-else statement* for checking authenticated users in *views.py*, but I haven't used any function for login in views.py. 
I am using django's default login sysyem and an *authentication.py* page for custom login (Authentication using an e-mail address).

> authentication.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """
    Authenticate using an e-mail address.
    """
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Please suggest me an efficient way of *redirecting* already authenticated users to the *home page* whenever they try to access login or signup pages through typing its URL on the browser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can redirect users by modifying your urls.py file like below:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
  path('signup/', views.register, name='register'),
  path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
]
```

This will redirect already authenticated users from the login page.
For the signup you will have to customize your register function add an if user is authenticated check.

Comment: @Wasi How can I specify a path to redirect to it?

Comment: You can use the `extra_context` dictionary to pass the redirect url  as value of `next`. Checkout the django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) for more information.

Comment: Nice, thank you Wasi (+1). Could only find reference to it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this decorator as well.

```
def login_excluded(redirect_to):
    """ This decorator kicks authenticated users out of a view """ 
    def _method_wrapper(view_method):
        def _arguments_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(redirect_to) 
            return view_method(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _arguments_wrapper
    return _method_wrapper
```

Then call it in your views.py.

```
@login_excluded('app:redirect_to_view')
def someview(request):
    # ...
```