# if user is already logged in do not show sign in form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have used User Creation Form for user registration.

```
class UserSignUpView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'core/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Account created successfully.'
```

When user is already logged in it should not see the signup form

Comment: So what should happen, redirect to a certain path? To where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent user to access login page in django when already logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062157/how-to-prevent-user-to-access-login-page-in-django-when-already-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive those things using **`dispatch()`** method of class based view

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserSignUpView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'core/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Account created successfully.'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            # User is already logged in, redirect them to another page
            return redirect('home')  # Redirect to the home page or any other desired URL
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```